# A WebApi error occurred InvalidOperationException: Incomplete protobuf payload received; got 0 of 30727 bytes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, protobuf-net, .net-core-3.0

Good morning.

I have a WebApi "GetByList" method written in NetCore 3.1 and C #.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Data/GetByList")]
public async Task<TagResultList> GetByList([FromBody] Entities.SearchParamsListApiModel searchParamsModel)
 {
    //some code
 }
```

Input method type:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class SearchParamsListApiModel : IValidatableObject
{
    [ProtoMember(1, Name = "SearchParamses")]
    public List<SearchParams> SearchParamses { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        return new SearchParamsListValidatable(SearchParamses).Validate(validationContext);
    }
}
```

Next, I wrote a class to test the call to this method.

```
public class GetDataPointsTests : WebApiClientTestsBase
{

    [Test]
    public void SearchParamListWithCorrectDataAndManyRows([Values(880, 881)] int searchParamsCount)
    {
        var searchParams = new List<SearchParams>();

        for (var i = 1; i <= searchParamsCount; i++)
        {
            searchParams.Add(new SearchParams
            {
                Tag = $"tag{i}",
                StartDateUTC = DateTime.MinValue.ToUniversalTime(),
                EndDateUTC = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Limit = int.MaxValue
            });
        }

        SignIn();

        var result = _webApiClient.GetDataPoints(searchParams);
    }
}
```

The first test (for 880 number of input parameters) is executed without errors, and the second test (for 881) is executed with the following error:

**System.InvalidOperationException: Incomplete protobuf payload received; got 0 of 30727 bytes**

**Q**: How do I correct this error?

Comment: Interesting. This is definitely coming from my code (https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/4989e03c1387a231561249744c6eabb9944a3d19/src/protobuf-net.AspNetCore/Formatters/ProtoInputFormatter.cs#L99), but I don't know *why* it is showing as a completed pipe; do you have a runnable minimal repro I could look at here? Also, this may be better logged on the protobuf-net repo.

Comment: Upgrading **protobuf-net** and **protobuf-net.AspNetCore** from **3.0.101** to **3.1.22** did not fix the problem.

Comment: I did not expect it to; I haven't seen this before, so I'd need to investigate it - it certainly isn't something I've fixed in recent builds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **LogTraceRequest(context)** method was found to be used as follows:

```
 app.Use((context, next) =>
 {
      LogTraceRequest(context);
      //other code
 }
```

and if you comment on this method, the error does not occur. The method was not written by me, so I followed the advice of its author.